Is there a way to access content of an Iframe of a website that I don't own?
I need to change text inside a page that includes iframe and i can't reach DOM it says something like cross origin, i am not a programmer so I don't know much technicalities I just want to edit text inside this webpage automatically ( I can edit from the developer tools but I want to make an extension that edits certain text in a certain way).
I tried chatgpt and it said that I need to have access to the back end to add the ability to receive messeges or something like that so my script can request the data it wants. but obviously I don't own that website.

Yeah no, because modifying others' website is a no-no and very privacy invasive. At most you could make an extension which could trigger on certain pages to automate replacing some things, but you won't do it from client-side code hosted on your website.

After a long time i figured out that i needed to add the permission to the content script all frames true, did that and it worked, I'm not modifying others' website I just wanted to automate a task, and I managed to do so, now I just wonder if they can detect that i am automating this task and not doing it manually, and if simulating user interaction by adding delays and events could suffice.
